# Save Multiple Data to 1 column in laravel

Tags: laravel

Do you have any idea or way on how to save 2 data in 1 column?
i have 2 datepicker field here which is from and to and i want to save it in the database looking like this

October 4, 2022 to October 5, 2022, can anyone share their idea

this is my migration by the way.

```
        Schema::create('leaves_admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('rec_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('date_filed')->nullable();
        $table->string('leave_type')->nullable();
        $table->string('requested_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('day')->nullable();
        $table->string('leave_reason')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->default('Pending');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

and my controller

```
    public function saveRecord(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([

        'leave_type'        => 'required|string|max:255',
        'from'              => 'required|string|max:255',
        'to'                => 'required|string|max:255',
        'day'               => 'required|string|max:255',
        'leave_reason'      => 'required|string|max:255',

    ]);
    
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try{   
        $dt             = Carbon::now();
        $todayDate      = $dt->toDayDateTimeString();
        $from           = new DateTime($request->from);
        $to             = new DateTime($request->to);
        $requested_date = "(".$from."-".$to.")";

        $leaves = new LeaveAdmin;
        $leaves->rec_id         = $request->rec_id;
        $leaves->name           = $request->name;
        $leaves->date_filed     = $todayDate;
        $leaves->leave_type     = $request->leave_type;
        $leaves->requested_date = $request->requested_date;
        $leaves->day            = $request->day;
        $leaves->leave_reason   = $request->leave_reason;
        $leaves->save();
        DB::commit();
        Toastr::success('Create new Leaves successfully','Success');
        return redirect()->back();


    }catch(\Exception $e){
        DB::rollback();
        Toastr::error('Add Leaves fail','Error');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it that way. If you didn't create this database layout you need to talk to who did and make them change it.

Each field should hold only one piece of information and one piece only. Doing it this way will make querying data easier (e.g., if you want to find everyone who left in a certain month or year the query is a straight select (`YEAR(leave_date) = 2022`)). If both start and leave dates are in the same field in the format you specify, you have to split the field, extract the information, and then perform your query.

Split the dates out and store them separately. Also, store them as standard `DATETIME` fields and convert them to strings within your Laravel code - easier queries, and you can change the format that a user sees much easier.